# Branching in PHP

Tags: php, branch

I have a php code, but every time I run this code, it always displays the results in the "else" block ---> "wrong", even though the userid and password are correct, please help. Thank you.

```html
<?php
  $userid_temp="admin";
  $password_temp="admin123";

  if($_POST['login'])
  {
    $userid=$_POST['$userid'];
    $password=$_POST['$password'];

    if($userid==$userid_temp and $password==$password_temp)
    {
      echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "wrong <br />";
    }
  }
?>
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="user id" /><br />
  <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="login" name="login" />
</form>
```

Comment: Change your $_POST['$userid'] with $_POST['userid'] same goes with password

Comment: On top of what @Sourabh said, you are looking for a Post key of `$userid` litterally.  So if `$userid = 1` you still are looking for `$userid` in the post array (the word not the number), because PHP does not replace variables with their value in single quoted string.  In anycase you probably don't want it replaced and instead want the word `userid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  $userid_temp = "admin";
  $password_temp = "admin123";

  if($_POST['login'])
  {
    $userid = $_POST['userid']; // $userid
    $password = $_POST['password']; // $password

    if($userid == $userid_temp and $password == $password_temp)
    {
      echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "wrong <br />";
    }
  }
?>

    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="user id" /><br />
      <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="password" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="login" name="login" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `var_dump($_POST); die();` in the `if (isset($_POST))` condition and you'll see the contents of what you are submitting.

Like @Sourabh and @ArtisticPhoenix said you're referencing a variable, but what you want is the parameter name in the `$_POST` array.

Drop the `$` and this should work.